# Zend Framework2 factory of service with different config

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2

I'm using Zend Framework2 and have created a service that does some work for me.
This service is used to create PDF files and needs to be configured with a hostname where Apache FOP is running.

I've written a PdfServiceFactory (implements \Zend\ServiceManager\FactoryInterface) that creates a PdfService instance and configures it with the required hostname.

For reasons not important to this question we need multiple of these services, each configured with a different hostname.
The code using these services does not know there are more than 1. They receive 1 service and simply use that one.

What would be the best way to do this?

- Do I need to write another Factory for this using the interface FactoryInterface?
- Can I set parameters in my module.config.php for each entry that will be passed into the factory?
- Something else?

I'm familiar with the way Symfony2 handles this, it is really easy to do there. As you can simply define multiple services and pass in a different argument in each.

In symfony it would look like this:

```
pdfservice.one:
    class: \Name\Space\PdfService
    arguments:
        - hostname.tld

pdfservice.two:
    class: \Name\Space\PdfService
    arguments:
        - anotherhostname.tld
```

But how to accomplish this in ZendFramework2 without creating a ton of factories.

Comment: You'd instantiate the Service and inject the required arguments afterwards.

Comment: Personally, I create multiple factories (instantiating the same class, injecting different args). However, if the constructor arguments are identical (and just the config differs) you could create an abstract factory (implementing `Zend\ServiceManager\AbstractFactoryInterface`).

Comment: Injecting afterwards would move the logic of the configuration of the service to multiple places, which is not desired for obvious reasons. If you request service X it should be ready to go.

Comment: AbstractFactories would work, but I dislike them being all checked when the container can't find it another way. You don't want too many of those.

Comment: Multiple factory classes is probably the best way to go in ZendFramework2. ALthough it might also be done in combination with closures in the configuration file, possible making it a bit more clean.